# ASP FileUpload with Image

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have `FileUpload` control on my ASP.NET page and `Image` control where I show image which is uploaded on server. What I want is for the `Image` control to show what I choose when I click on Browse in `FileUpload` control before I upload on server. This way, the user can see what they are uploading.

I am using C# with ASP.NET 4

Comment: Does it have to be a preview before the image is uploaded to the server at all?  Or would it suffice to upload the image in the background and display a preview once it's complete (providing a very similar user experience overall)?

Comment: Sure, that may work. Just thought that the way I mentioned would be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's going to be JavaScript involved with something like this, be aware of that.  There's no setting on the out-of-the-box ASP.NET controls to accomplish this.  (Mostly because the standard `input type="file"` doesn't support this.)

A quick Google search turned up [a jQuery plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) that seems to do the job quite effectively.  I checked my web inspector window while adding a file and, sure enough, it doesn't seem to post to the server prior to displaying the preview.

In their [Setup documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup) you'll want the section entitled "Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with a custom server-side upload handler."  [Their wiki](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) also has links to sample ASP.NET code.